# How do I get to my prometheus graphs?

Tags: python, prometheus

I've installed the python prometheus client (prometheus-client==0.0.18) and added several metrics to my app.

I'm importing and running the prometheus client 
from prometheus_client import 
...
start_http_server(8100)

and I can see my metrics on http://{my_ip}:8100/

and as per the documentation here:
https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/getting_started/ 
I expected to find the expression browser at /graph
but that just brings me back to the metrics page (as does anything else after the slash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to also run Prometheus itself and configure it to scrape the metrics that you have made available from your application via the prometheus python client.

https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus

The expression browser and graphs you're after will be available at `http:{your_ip}:9090/`